# Replacing 1 variable in 1 column with variables in aonther column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a database in which one column `D2` is marked with 3 different variables `NA`, `Year`, `Prefer Not To Answer`. I want to replace the `Year` with the numeric answers in the second column `D2_TEXT`

I am using Rstudio and I have dplyr and tidyverse installed.

[Database Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxsLQ.png)

Comment: Here's some advice on learning the difference between [wide and long data](https://www.statology.org/long-vs-wide-data/#:~:text=A%20dataset%20can%20be%20written,repeat%20in%20the%20first%20column.&text=Notice%20that%20in%20the%20wide,the%20first%20column%20is%20unique.)

Comment: `your_data <- mutate(your_data, D2 = ifelse(D2 == 'Year', D2_TEXT, D2))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_data <- mutate(your_data, D2 = ifelse(D2 == 'Year', D2_TEXT, D2))
```

Thank you Axeman